# loop ienumerable and get values

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, linq-to-objects

I need to get values from this linq:

```
var joinPreRes = (from t1 in db.preguntas_respuestas
                  join t2 in db.respuesta1
                  on t1.id_respuesta equals t2.id
                  where t1.id_pregunta == id
                  group new
                  {
                      t1.id,
                      t1.id_respuesta,
                      t2.respuesta_visual,
                      t2.respuesta_valor
                  } by t1.id);


foreach (var a in joinPreRes)
{


}
```

how can access to id or id_respuesta_visual on foreach???

Comment: When you debug this, what properties does `a` have?

Comment: @David: Not even debug, intellisense should be able to give the OP the answer.

Comment: Accessing `id_respuesta_visual` in your `foreach`does not make sense, you grouped by a different criteria, there is no unique `id_respuesta_visual` for each `a`.

Comment: @David they have  linq methods

Comment: @vrvictor: "linq methods" as in the standard `IEnumerable` extension methods used by LINQ?  If that's the case then `a` is a collection.  It's not really clear what your data structure (or intended data structure) is here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a group, so you should iterate the grouped items.

```
var joinPreRes = from t1 in db.preguntas_respuestas
                          join t2 in db.respuesta1
                          on t1.id_respuesta equals t2.id
                          where t1.id_pregunta == id
                          group new
                          {
                              t1.id,
                              t1.id_respuesta,
                              t2.respuesta_visual,
                              t2.respuesta_valor
                          } by t1.id into GroupedItems
                          select GroupedItems;


foreach (var a in joinPreRes)
{
    // a.Key   is the t1.id

    foreach (var subItem in a)
    {
        // subItem.id_respuesta   <-   other fields/properties
        // subItem.respuesta_valor   <-   other fields/properties
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use select function 
        Select(x => x.id && x.respuesta_visual);

Answer (score 0):

probably you need

```
group new
{
    t1.id,
    t1.id_respuesta,
    t2.respuesta_visual,
    t2.respuesta_valor
} by new
{
    t1.id,
    t1.id_respuesta,
    t2.respuesta_visual,
    t2.respuesta_valor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `a` you come across will be an `IGrouping` where the `Key` is an integer, and there are one or more elements in the grouping.

Since the `id` is used as the `Key` you can get the `id` just from `a.Key`.

The rest of the properties can be accessed by treating `a` as an `IQueryable`. For example:

```
var firstRespuesta = a.First().id_respuesta;

foreach(var item in a)
{
  DoSomething(item.respuesta_visual);
}
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies in the fact that the `a` variable in the `foreach` loop is a collection of anonymous objects with the properties defined in the `group new` block. Therefore, to access theses items you could do the following in the `foreach` block:

```
foreach (var a in joinPreRes)
{
   foreach (var item in a)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(item.id);
      Console.WriteLine(item.id_respuesta_visual);
   }
}
```

Of course, you do not have to have an inner 'foreach' loop, but that is the easiest way for me to show you how to access the anonymous items.